# Fetching data from a webpage

Tags: java, android-studio

I need to fetch data from the website "https://www.arbatunity.com/index.php", I want the data from the top right of the website that says current market profit.
I need this as a string value that can be updated.

Comment: You should look into HTML parsing in Java through JSoup: https://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 1):

With the JSoup library, this is easy:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.arbatunity.com/index.php").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("#id_profit b");
String percent = ""
for (Element e : elements) {
    percent = e.html();
}
//percent holds the String you're looking for
```